# How to export jcr:security in Jackrabbit?

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr, sling

I am developing an apache sling WCMS. I want to export security contents (users and groups)
to an xml file.

I used the following code but there is an exception:

```java
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("d:\\bk.xml");
session.exportSystemView("/rep:security", output, false, false);
output.flush();
output.close();
```

And the exception here:

```
javax.jcr.PathNotFoundException: /rep:security
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemManager.getItem(ItemManager.java:545)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.getItem(SessionImpl.java:876)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.AbstractSession.export(AbstractSession.
java:541)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.AbstractSession.exportDocumentView(Abst
ractSession.java:237)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.AbstractSession.exportDocumentView(Abst
ractSession.java:279)....
```

Is it a true way to export users and groups?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I was ignored where `rep:security` is located. `rep:security` is in `security` workspace of the repository so if I want to export it's contents I should log in security workspace before.

I corrected the code as follow and could export rep:security:

```
Session securitySession = session.getRepository().login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "XXX".toCharArray()), "security");
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("d:\\bk.xml");
securitySession.exportSystemView("/rep:security", output, false, false);
output.flush();
output.close();
```